# Deleted items being returned in query from DynamoDB

Tags: react-native, amazon-dynamodb

I've deleted items from AdminUI in the 'Content' section, and I have deleted items also from 'items' in DynamoDB in AWS. The items do not appear on either 'Content' in AdminUI and not in the DynamoDB table, however when I query the following code, and then console.warn the array that comes back, I see the deleted items in react-native warn and I also see them in the Metro console but in the Metro console they have a value of "_deleted". How can I permanently get rid of the deleted items in the DB?

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const getCurrentUser = async () => {
          const userId = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    
          const dbUsers = await DataStore.query(User, uzer =>
            uzer.sub('eq', userId.attributes.sub),
          );
    
          console.warn(dbUsers);
    };

    getCurrentUser();
  }, []);
```

This is what I see in the Metro console:

```
 WARN  [{"_deleted": undefined, "_lastChangedAt": undefined, "_version": undefined, "bio": "My bio", "gender": "", "id": "70cead42-6140-47ee-910b-ec0983cac170", "image": "https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/elon.png", "lookingFor": "FEMALE", "name": "Omerle", "sub": "68f43e08-42a1-46f8-a10e-39b92d80be88"}, {"_deleted": undefined, "_lastChangedAt": undefined, "_version": undefined, "bio": "This is my Bio", "gender": "", "id": "106fa724-5a9a-4be7-b369-3c4cfba18be0", "image": "https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/avatars/elon.png", "lookingFor": "FEMALE", "name": "Omer", "sub": "68f43e08-42a1-46f8-a10e-39b92d80be88"}]
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/1391) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using DataStore, it first queries your data from the DynamoDB and then for all subsequent queries it retrieves the data from your device's local cache. Clearing the cache on your local device might solve your problem. More information here: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/

Comment: Resetting the cache doesn't work however what worked eventually was clearing DataStore inside the code that I took from one of the links in the link you sent:
Amplify.DataStore.clear();